# How to fix wordpress login attempts. I have deleted wp-login.php, and still getting attempts?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, security, authentication, brute-force

Check list of Items I have done:-

1. added new salts (better security pro paid plugin = max'd out security)
   brute force attack is on and has not stopped all attempts.
2. changed login (simple wp login plugin)
3. monitor file change (simple history plugin)
4. monitor live actions (wordfence plugin)
5. deleted wp-login.php (add using ftp program when I want to login)
6. deleted admin.php (didn't make a difference still get login attempts)
7. changed the nickname and deleted old user so public see fake name

There must be another way these login attempts ares still coming in
I just delete the ajax login from the admin folder

Is this a plugin exploit?
Is it possible to be a database attack? 
How would I monitor the mysql?

Answer (score 0):

There's really nothing you can do to prevent someone from sending HTTP requests to your server, which is what is most likely going on. I assume that you are seeing these login requests in your log files?

My suggestion would be to deploy a web application firewall of some kind, which is independent of WordPress and is designed to integrate with Apache or Nginx, such as [ModSecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org/) which is OpenSource. This will at least give you some more options at the web application layer.